# Add image to center of toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I am using Toolbar instead of actionabar in my appliaction.The toolbar works fine but the problem is that i want the app logo to appear in the center of the toolbar.The image will be in center if no menu items are displayed on the toolbar, but if i add search or refresh menu item to the toolbar the image also shifts.I want the toolbar to be in center always

Code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/pink"
                android:minHeight="56dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_toolbar_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_home_header"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/image"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                         />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Just add your items manually in the relative layout. no need to use the default buttons. It is so simple and you can do anything with the toolbar view.

Comment: But i need the the overflow pop

Comment: @ArchanaVetkar You could make your own overflow menu if needs be. It's just a simple `dialog` containing a `ListView`. You could probably make something better to be honest.

Comment: Yeah you can just make a custom view just like that. Just a little bit of search needed.

Answer (score 5):

Using a bitmap drawable with center gravity as Toolbar background helps you create the required effect. e.g.,

Let's assume your image to be centered is **centeree.png**, and that will be wrapped inside **drawable/toolbar_background.xml**

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/centeree"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

You can assign **toolbar_background.xml** as a background to toolbar in your layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background">
```

---

Also as an alternative, you can use a 9 patch drawable with a equal stretchable area on both sides.

Comment: I had to change "android:src="@android:drawable/centeree" to android:src="@drawable/centeree" to make this work. Clever solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it because of

> One or more custom views. The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have been measured.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to do it, although its probably not the right way to do it.

I set my right side padding to the same width as my hamburger icon. Then everything else what I wanted in my dimens.xml. May need to be adjusted if you are adding action items on the right.

@dimen/app_bar_padding_right = 72dp

```xml
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/app_bar_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_bar_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/app_bar_padding_right"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_bar_logo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Add these attributes to the ImageView...

```
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```